# Count Records within 30 days of today

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I Have a model an Opportunity model that has an attribute called date_of_opportunity. I am trying to write a method that counts how many opportunities are within 30 days of today.  However when I try to call my method in the console, I get the error 'undefined local variable or method'

Here is my model:

```
class Opportunity < ActiveRecord::Base
     def calculate_num_days
         num_days = 0
         @opportunity = Opportunity.all
         @opportunity.each do |opportunity|
        if (opportunity.date_of_opportunity - Date.today < 30)
            num_days = num_days + 1
            return num_days
        end
         end

        end
end
```

Can someone help me figure out whats wrong? Thanks!!

Comment: Where do you define  `@opportunities` ?

Comment: What is `@opportunities.est_rfp_date`?

Comment: @user1547174 there you have defined `@opportunity` but you are using `@opportunities` did you check that?

Comment: @user1547174 `@opportunity.date_of_opportunity.each do |opportunity|` should be `@opportunity.each do`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will get counts how many opportunities are within 30 days of today, you can try this :

```
class Opportunity < ActiveRecord::Base

 def self.calculate_num_days(from = (Date.today-1.month).beginning_of_day,to = Date.today.end_of_day)
   where(date_of_opportunity: from..to).count
 end

end
```

And on your console you can type like this

```
Opportunity.calculate_num_days
```

Output looks like :

```
irb(main):001:0> Opportunity.calculate_num_days
←[0m←[1m←[35m (51.0ms)←[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "opportunities" WHERE ("opportunities"."date_of_opportunity" BETWEEN '2014-05-04 00:00:00.000000' AND '2014-06-04 23:59:59.999999')
=> 2
```

Comment: works great! just curious, but why do i need to put in "self"?

Comment: @user1547174 `self.` will make it a class method. `self.method_name` indicates a class method; `method_name` indicates an instance method. You can read more about it in here en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a class method, but are defining an instance method. Do this:

```
def self.calculate_num_days
 ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, `@opportunity = Opportunity.all` should be `@opportunities = Opportunity.all`

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing what you are trying to do I would let ActiveRecord do the heavy lifting. `Opportunity.where("date_of_opportunity - :today < 30", today: Date.today).size`

Disclaimer, this is completely untested

Comment: yeah, I am trying to do something like that...but i figured writing a method would be easier than trying to write the query itself..

Comment: Fair enough. Depending on the number of records it might be beneficial to pass some of the load off to the DB.